# how to create jar file in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I want to create independent jar files in netbeans like we can do in eclipse. Normally people suggest to clean and built the project and there is a jar file created. But to run these jar file the .java files, the codes are also required. Isn't there any way to create jar files which runs independently without requiring java codes?
Thanks

Comment: export them as runnable jar

Comment: In most cases sources are not required. You can run `java -jar dist/myproject.jar` withouth having any `*.java` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. set the main class in run configuration
2. do a clean build
3. go to the dist folder and you can find the jar there as a runnable one

for further information refer this [Creating_an_Executable_Java_File_in_NetBeans](http://usarsim.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Creating_an_Executable_Java_File_in_NetBeans)