# how to generate executable jar file of java class file in netbeans 8.1?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

i have the following code

```
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.awt.Robot;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.*;


    public class screen2image
     {
       SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd hh mm ss a");

     public void robo() throws Exception
     {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
    ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File("E:/java/AutoScreenShot\\"+formatter.format(now.getTime())+".jpg"));
    System.out.println(formatter.format(now.getTime()));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    screen2image s2i = new screen2image();
    while(1==1)
    {
        s2i.robo();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

}

and i've written that code in screen2image.java class file. It is running fine . but now i want to make a executable jar file of this code so that it can be run by anyone. i've implemented following steps:

```
    1. right click on my project -> go to properties -> go to build -> packaging -> then there is a problem there they are showing screenshot.war file istead of jar file
```

i'm using Netbeans 8.1, i've search everywhere i'm unable to get anything which can help me through it. I've downloaded **JWrapper** and tried to make a executable jar file from it but still it is not happening after running that executable jar file there shows no main manifest found, then i write **Main-Class : "my class name and Class-path: "path of my class"** in Manifest.mf file but still not working..
i'm unable to understand where i'm getting wrong. please help me if anyone knows about it.. I'll be thankful to u

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196200/how-to-create-jar-file-in-netbeans

Comment: Stephen : the link you have mentioned i've tried it before but problem is that in run category there is no option of setting main class in my IDE as i've stated earlier i'm using netbeans latest version 8.1 now what to do how to set main class in this iDE can you tell me what is the role of VM options